# Activity has leaked ServiceConnection eroror in Android

Tags: android, cordova, text-to-speech, serviceconnection, connection-leaks

My application is developed through Phone-Gap. But when we turn-on TALK_BACK option from accessibility then I am getting the error message like below and the application is crashing for some time (but not always). How can I resolve it?

```
    7559-7559/com.mdlive.mobile E/ActivityThread? Activity com.mdlive.mobile.MDLIVEMain has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$Connection@44c85aa8 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.mdlive.mobile.MDLIVEMain has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$Connection@44c85aa8 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:988)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:882)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1949)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1932)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:529)
        at com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient.doBindService(SelfBrailleClient.java:125)
        at com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient.access$1000(SelfBrailleClient.java:43)
        at com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$SelfBrailleHandler.handleRebindService(SelfBrailleClient.java:260)
        at com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$SelfBrailleHandler.handleMessage(SelfBrailleClient.java:245)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```